# How to for_each and for loop for EC2, security group, and ebs volumes?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm new to Terraform and wanted to know if there's a way for me to do this. I want to create multiple EC2 instance with it's own security group, and attach volumes of different sizes and types.

```
module "ec2_sg" {
  source              = "../../modules/sgs"
  for_each            = var.ec2_info
  name                = each.value.name
  description         = "Security group for ${each.value.name}"
  vpc_id              = each.value.vpc
  ingress_cidr_blocks = each.value.ingress_cidr_blocks
  ingress_rules       = each.value.ingress_rules
  egress_cidr_blocks  = each.value.egress_cidr_blocks
  egress_rules        = each.value.egress_rules
}

module "ec2_instance" {
  source = "../../modules/ec2"
  for_each                    = var.ec2_info
  name                        = each.value.name
  ami                         = var.AMIS.linux_ami
  instance_type               = each.value.ec2_instance_type
  vpc_security_group_ids      = module.ec2_sg.security_group_id[each.key]
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "volume_disk" {
  for_each          = var.ec2_info
  type              = each.value.type
  iops              = each.value.iops
  availability_zone = each.value.availability_zone
  size              = each.value.size
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "volume_disk" {
  for_each    = var.ec2_info
  device_name = each.value.device_name
  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.data1[each.key].id
  instance_id = module.ec2_instance.id[each.key]
}
```

This is what I've tried so far but I can't get the volume part to work. The ec2_info contains information about the 2 different EC2 instances I want to create. What kind of data manipulation should I do to achieve this? Do you think using separate variable for the disks will achieve this? Something like:

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "volume_disk" {
  for_each          = var.disks_info
  type              = each.value.type
  iops              = each.value.iops
  availability_zone = each.value.availability_zone
  size              = each.value.size
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "volume_disk" {
  for_each    = var.disks_info
  device_name = each.value.device_name
  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.data1[each.key].id
  instance_id = module.ec2_instance.id[each.key]
}
```

But if I do this? How do I ensure each disks connect to the intended EC2 instance? Thank you.

Comment: " I can't get the volume part to work." - what exactly is happening? What are the errors?

Comment: What is `var.disks_info`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the "count" parameter.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html